# Annett Louisan - Liebeslied - Hilfe bei der Interpretation

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, poetry

Folgende Zeilen aus diesem wunderschönen deutschsprachigen Chanson sind mir etwas unklar:

> Meine Zweifel waren ihr Geld nicht wert

Um wessen Geld handelt es sich? Um das der Zweifel? Wie können Zweifel Geld haben?

und:

> Meine Züge entgleisen im Takt

mir ist klar, dass dieser Song sehr viel poetische Doppeldeutigkeiten enthält, aber diese eine ist mir unklar. Bei dem Wortspiel, dass Züge entgleisen, fehlt mir die zweite Interpretation von *Zügen*. Um welche Züge handelt es sich? Gesichtszüge? Charakterzüge? Etwas anderes?

Für mehr Kontext:
http://www.songtexte.com/songtext/annett-louisan/das-liebeslied-73da7691.html

Comment: Das sind zwei Fragen. Allein schon, dass der Titel der Frage ein Titel eines Songs ist (Chancon sagt man nicht) und eben keinen Bezug auf die eigentlichen Fragen nimmt, zeigt, dass es besser wäre, die Fragen in zwei Posts aufzuteilen.

Comment: Doch, das ist Chancon. So nennt sich die Musikgattung. Außerdem glaube ich nicht, dass es sinnvoll ist, das aufzuteilen. Mal ehrlich...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, die Texte von Annett Louisan.... Bilder über Bilder und doppelte Bedeutungen...

Aber zum Thema:

> Meine Zweifel waren ihr Geld nicht wert 
>   sie ergaben sich stumm

Wenn etwas *sein Geld nicht wert* ist, dann taugt es nicht viel oder ist nicht haltbar- frei übersetzt kann man das als kurzes Aufflackern von Zweifel lesen.

> Meine Züge entgleisen im Takt 
>   Und machen vor keinem mehr halt

Das ist ein schönes Spiel mit der doppelten Bedeutung von Zügen: Gemeint sind die Gesichtszüge, aber sie benutzt Vokabeln die auch für den Bahnverkehr genutzt werden: entgleisen, Takt, haltmachen. Das führt zu dem "Stolpern" beim Hören/Lesen, ist aber sicher so gewollt, weil genau darin der Reiz liegt.

Comment: Ist das mit dem *sein Geld nicht wert sein* ein idiomatischer Ausdruck?

Comment: Ja. Kann wörtlich ("das Ding dass ich mir bei A..I gekauft habe, und das nicht richtig funktioniert") oder im übertragenen Sinn benutzt werden. Geht mit oder ohne "nicht", je nach Aussage. Das Äquivalent im englischen wäre "worth his salt".

Comment: Im Nachklapp zu der Frage "idiomatischer Ausdruck": ein verwandter Ausdruck ist "das Papier nicht wert sein (...auf das es gedruckt ist)", was die Wertlosigkeit der Aussage oder den fehlenden Bestand einer Vereinbarung ausdrückt.

Comment: eigentlich ist "sein Geld wert sein" der idiomatische Ausdruck und das heißt einfach, dass etwas definitiv das Wert war, was man bezahlt hat. Die "nicht"-Version ist das Gegenteil, das mit "funktioniert nicht richtig" ist aber reininterpretiert.

Answer (score 2):

> Meine Zweifel waren ihr Geld nicht wert

bedeutet hier nur

> Meine Zweifel waren unnötig

da sicherlich kein Geld im Spiel war, sondern ein Reim auf "begehrt" gesucht wurde.

Mit

> Meine Züge entgleisen im Takt

können nur die Gesichtszüge gemeint sein.